TypeError: Cannot Read Properties of Undefined (Reading 'equals') in Luxon with MUI DatePicker
I'm encountering a TypeError when using luxon with the DatePicker component from MUI's @mui/x-date-pickers. The error message is:
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'equals')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'equals')
    at AdapterLuxon.setTimezone (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:36563:23)
    at Object.setTimezone (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51270:73)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50620:99
    at mountMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85652:23)
    at Object.useMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:86037:20)
    at Object.useMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:106497:25)
    at useValueWithTimezone (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50620:72)
    at usePickerValue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50146:85)
    at usePicker (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49845:97)
    at useDesktopPicker (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46865:69)

This error occurs in the following code when I try to use the DatePicker component:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Grid, TextField, Typography, FormControlLabel, Radio, RadioGroup, FormControl, FormLabel, Button, Autocomplete, Stack } from '@mui/material';
import { DatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { AdapterLuxon } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterLuxon';
import { Settings, DateTime } from 'luxon';

// Set Luxon to use the UK locale globally
Settings.defaultLocale = 'en-GB';
Settings.defaultZone = 'utc';

function FlightDetails({ formik }) {
  // Code for handling form logic

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon} adapterLocale="en-GB">
    <DatePicker
      label="Return Date"
      name="returnDate"
      value={
        formik.values.returnDate &&
        DateTime.fromISO(formik.values.returnDate).isValid
          ? DateTime.fromISO(formik.values.returnDate)
          : null
      }
      onChange={(newValue) => {
        formik.setFieldValue('returnDate', newValue ? newValue.toISO() : '');
      }}
      onBlur={() => formik.setFieldTouched('returnDate')}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          error={formik.touched.returnDate && Boolean(formik.errors.returnDate)}
          helperText={formik.touched.returnDate ? formik.errors.returnDate : null}
        />
      )}
      inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
      fullWidth
    />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}

export default FlightDetails;

Additional Information
Packages Used: @mui/material, @mui/x-date-pickers, luxon
Error Occurrence: The error occurs during rendering when the DatePicker component attempts to process date values.
What I've Tried:
Ensured AdapterLuxon and luxon are correctly installed and imported.
Wrapped DatePicker with LocalizationProvider.
Validated DateTime.fromISO() to ensure only valid dates are passed.
How can I resolve this TypeError related to equals when using luxon with MUI's DatePicker? Are there any issues with how DateTime objects are being handled, or is there a specific way to integrate luxon and MUI's DatePicker?
Any guidance on fixing this error or improving my implementation would be greatly appreciated!
